# How to fix 'TypeError: expecting string or bytes object' error in Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sql-insert

I want to insert a row into table. But i got TypeError: expecting string or bytes object this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "d:\Git\Repos\mavi\oracle_connection.py", line 19, in 
>       c.prepare(QUERY,{"expr":expr, "expr2":expr2}) TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

```
import cx_Oracle
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(***)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(***)
c = conn.cursor()

expr = bytes('', 'utf-8')
expr2 = bytes('ML_TEST', 'utf-8')

QUERY = '''
    INSERT INTO dev_log (LOG, SQ_DEV_LOG_ID, LF_TEKLIF_WS, PACKAGE BODY, LINE_NO)
    VALUES
    (:expr,:expr,:expr2,:expr,:expr)
'''

rows = [] 

c.prepare(QUERY,{"expr":expr, "expr2":expr2})      
c.executemany(None, rows)
conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Your posted code only contains 21 lines. Are you sure you're not leaving something out?

Comment: @HampusLarsson yes there was comments, i edited

Comment: Şevval, can you descibe your table so that we can see the data types of the columns ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan with order <CLOB> , int , string, string, int

Comment: I think, this explains the issue, since, substitution variable `expr` is used for `integer`, `string` and `clob` at the same time.

Comment: but they except null s actually @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: also what @user3592246 commented below is a nice catch.

Comment: yes @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
c.prepare(QUERY)      
c.executemany(None, [{"expr":expr, "expr2":expr2}])
```

From the docs, it looks like you should be passing your parameters to `executemany`, not `prepare`.

https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html

Comment: Now it gives this error " c.executemany(None, [{"expr":expr, "expr2":expr2}])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00917: missing comma "

Comment: That's probably because your column "PACKAGE BODY" has a space in the name, you should specify it in quotes.

Comment: how can i fix it? how should i represent it?